# Replacing dvd drive with internal HDD through caddy

Tags: mount, hard-drive, dvd, cd

I have replaced my internal SATA hard disk with SATA SSD and then I installed ubuntu 20.04 on my ssd. After that I have replaced cd/dvd drive with my previously internal hard disk by using caddy but I can't see dvd or cdrom file in `/dev` to mount using `sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media`
Can anyone please help, what should I do ?

Comment: I would expect it to show up as /dev/sdb.

Comment: @SiepKroonenberg. No, sdb is not showing in /dev. Can you please check [here] (https://seashells.io/v/2QW2GMN3). These are the things in /dev.

Comment: Look under /dev/disk, and in particular under /dev/disk/by-path whether there is anything you recognize. Of course, it is always possible that there is something wrong with the connection between the motherboard and the caddy, or between the caddy and the disk.

Comment: @SiepKroonenberg, In /dev/disk/by-path, I am getting these 3 things https://seashells.io/v/vvz87nUj. I don't have any idea about it. If possible, Could you please tell me what should I have to do now. I guess it is related to internal ssd.

Comment: Yes, that looks like the internal disk and its partitions. It looks like the disk in your caddy is not seen at all. I should check those connections. Also, have a really close look whether the caddy does not contain any switchers or sliders, which might make a difference.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I'll check it.